# Error in ggplot2 geom_density in R studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using following code to plot density of 2 variables: Vehicle velocity and svel. But R throws an error:

```
>p <- ggplot(data=final.data, aes(`Vehicle velocity`))+geom_density(aes(color=I('red')))
>p
>Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type AsIs. Defaulting to continuous
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

What's the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the I in `color=I('red')` supposed to be there? Otherwise it could be the data format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass some aesthetics in `aes` call only if it is a mapping to some variable. See the difference between

```
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) + geom_density(color = "red")
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) + geom_density(aes(color = "red"))
```

In both calls, there is no need for `I()`.